# problems with inheritance of variables over many pages

Tags: php

I have this code on bootconfig.php that is loaded in all of my pages.

```
// What languages do we support
$available_langs = array('en','it');

// Set our default language session
$_SESSION['lang'] = 'en';   

if(isset($_GET['lang']) && $_GET['lang'] != ''){ 
// check if the language is one we support
if(in_array($_GET['lang'], $available_langs))
{       
  $_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang']; // Set session
}
}
// Include active language
      include($_SESSION['path'].'languages/'.$_SESSION['lang'].'/lang.'.$_SESSION['lang'].'.php');




//Include LIB
include($_SESSION['path']."lib/auth.class.php");
include($_SESSION['path']."lib/register.class.php");
include($_SESSION['path']."lib/string.class.php");


//Include Other Config File
require_once('./config/stringsecure.php');
require_once("./config/menuconfig.php");
require_once("./config/headerconfig.php");
require_once("./config/contentconfig.php");
require_once("./config/forumconfig.php");
require_once("./config/titleconfig.php");
require_once("./include/vocaboli/vocaboliconf.php");
```

in the file lang.en.php i have for example $lang['contactme'] but if i use it in menuconfig.php it doesn't exist...
if i put echo $lang['contactme'] at the end of bootconfig it works but in menuconfig not. why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it is a simple scoping issue. Probably in one of the cases you are inside a function.
Inside a function you can't access global variables.

Probably `$GLOBALS['lang']['contactme']` would work.

See the details here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 0):

As it stands here **menuconfig** will appear in **bootconfig** but not the other way around.

I think the includes are backwards: if you want `$lang` to appear in **menuconfig** you need to use `require_once( 'bootconfig.php' )` in that file.

Comment: yes but it is for languages, i can't include bootconfig in all of my file... is there another method?